# Unknown Filesystem Type 'msdos'

Tags: 13.04, mount, virtualization, fstab, qemu

I'm trying to mount a disk image with FreeDOS I have so I can move some old DOS programs over to play through QEMU as a test for a friend who has to use DOS programs at her work. When I try to mount the image using mount, I get a `unknown filesystem type 'msdos'` error. The manpage states that msdos is supported, but apparently it can't be used. I added it in my fstab. The line is `/home/user/freedos.img /mnt/freedos msdos loop,offset=32256 0 0` Is there something I need to get and install to support MSDOS fstypes or is Ubuntu not supporting MSDOS period?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the [dosfstools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dosfstools&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all) package.

To install:

```
 sudo apt-get install dosfstools
```

You shouldn't have to reboot in order to mount, but if it doesn't work right after installing, try rebooting.

Comment: try this
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install  exfat-utils